# Why do we do one-hot encoding in language modelling?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

Could anyone explain why one-hot encoding is good in language modelling? (exspecially in deep learning)

(I know that other encoding methods such as word2vec is better, I just want to know at the root why one-hot encoding works).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The main application of one-hot encoding is to represent symbols with vectors without any prior bias. 'book', 'apple', 'library' are symbolic representations without any measurable values.

There are two places we use one-hot encoding in neural networks:
1. encoding the inputs 2. encoding the predicted outputs.

The inputs of neural networks are known as feature representations, and outputs are working as components of lookup tools (find the value in index `i`). But, I would like to argue that both are in fact tools for the lookup operation.

The most important properties that neural networks are looking for in any computation operation are 1. differentiability and 2. parallelization with GPUs. Lookup operation, if it is done like indexing items and finding them based on an integer index, is not a differentiable operation and it is not possible to be done easily in parallel, but if the items subjected to this operations are vectors, the indices can be represented as one-hot vectors  and the lookup operations can be a simple matrix multiplication of the vector of vectors (matrix of numbers) and the one-hot representation of the indices. This multiplication operation is both parallelizable and differentiable.

When you represent an input word with one-hot encoding `x`, the result of multiplying it with a matrix `W` is working as a lookup operation (this is what we know as embedding layer) and if the output labels `y` with one-hot encoding the multiplication of the output `y'` and transposed `y` is the exact value in the intended index (usually the probability or logit of the predicting the label). This representation is not always the optimum way to perform this, that is why you often find 'sparse' alternatives in modern frameworks: i.e. `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` for outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination Mehdi.